# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>' to 'T'

Tags: linq, crm, linqpad

Following piece of code, I'm using in the LinqPad 4 with the 'Dynamics CRM LinqPad Driver'. It will execute the code against the CRM Online instance. While, executing this code I'm getting 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'UserQuery.Container1'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)' at the highlighted BOLD line.

```
void Main() {

string[] chosenOnes = {
"oamaweral@abc.com",
"rflefel@abc.com",
};

IQueryable<Container1> zVar = ContactSet.Where(a => a.EMailAddress1 == "uiuiyh@abc.com")
                              .Select( a => new Container1() { FullName = a.FullName } );
foreach(string element in chosenOnes)
    **zVar.Concat(new Container1[]{(ContactSet.Where(a => a.EMailAddress1 == element)
          .Select( a => new Container1() { FullName = a.FullName } ))} );**

zVar.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Container1
{
    public string FullName {get; set; } 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your array initialization attempt is not correct. Just use `ToArray()` instead :

```
zVar.Concat(
    ContactSet.Where(a => a.EMailAddress1 == element)
              .Select(a => new Container1() { FullName = a.FullName })
              .ToArray()
);
```